# Access to C:\Users unauthorized when running .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, settings, access-denied

I am migrating a library from .NET Framework to .NET Core. In this library, I offer a convenient way to save XML data in the user's `AppData` folder.

When running under .Net Core, I get an exception:

> Access to the path 'C:\Users' is denied

The value of _userDataPath at that time is:

> C:\Users\cedbo\AppData\Roaming\MyApp

This works fine under .NET Framework, so it is not an authorization problem.

```
// compute filepath
_userDataPath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
    appName);

_userDataFile = Path.Combine(_userDataPath, "UserData.xml");

// load data or create file if required.
T userData = null;

if (File.Exists(_userDataFile)) // !!! Returns false even when file exists
{
    userData = XmlTools.GetFromXml<T>(_userDataFile);
}
else
{
    userData = new T();

    if (!Directory.Exists(_userDataPath))  // !!! Returns false even when directory exists
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(_userDataPath);  // Exception: Access to the path 'C:\Users' is denied.
    }

    XmlTools.SaveToXml<T>(userData, _userDataFile);
}
```

I am ready to use another standard approach if .NET Core proposes one, but I didn't find anything neither on this write access limitation, nor on another way to store user data recommended in .NET Core.

Can anyone please advise?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the value in `_userDataPath` ?

Comment: It almost looks like the path being combined is incorrect... Can you hard-code the exact path to the XML file, just to verify this is indeed an access issue *to the right path*?

Comment: @CoolBots In debug mode, I see the path is correct in my variable. This happens before talking about the XML file, it is when creating the containing folder, whatever would go inside.

Comment: Did additional checks: testing if xml file and containing folder exist will not crash, but return false even when these elements actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my findings:

I was trying to run this code from a UWP application. I tried but couldn't write anything either on other locations such as C:\ or D:\ drives (D: is a second hard drive).

I eventually found that UWP files access if different from what I used to do with WPF for instance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

For instance, `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` will return a `StorageFolder` object that contains methods such as `CreateFile`, `GetItemsAsync`, etc. This is typically the place where I would store user data if I wanted to keep it in a file. See https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder?view=winrt-19041 for more information.

Given this substantial change in the way I'd store user data, I will consider using EntityFrameworkCore on a sqlite database instead:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases

I hope that sharing this adventure will help others facing the same situation.

Happy coding to all!